# I can't get rowdeleting in gridview to delete database entry

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I'm currently in the process of creating an asp.net web app in C# using Visual Studio. I have been stuck on the same problem for a while now and have tried so many solutions. I am required to have a page that upon loading, displays some of the information stored in a database table (first name, dob & username (PK) for children that have registered on a previous page.

I have no problem populating the grid view with this data, but I am required to have delete button/links next to each child, that delete the child completely from the database table. This is what I can not get to work. My code was a complete mess, full of commented out sections where I was trying new things. As of right now, I have scaled it back to a simple section of code, and I am getting an error when clicking delete next to any of the children in gridview.

Is it really this difficult to enable the delete function in gridview? I have supplied screenshots, along with my code. If anyone can point out where i'm going wrong, I would be ever so grateful! Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of error I get when hitting delete]

.CS CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Coursework
{
public partial class viewandremove : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THEBEAST;Initial Catalog=newregDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [firstname], [dob], [ChildID] FROM [children]", connect))
        {
            connect.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            connect.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }      
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {          
        using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THEBEAST;Initial Catalog=newregDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM children where childID=", connect))
        {
            connect.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            connect.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

SOURCE CODE:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="viewandremove.aspx.cs" Inherits="Coursework.viewandremove" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<p>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="childID" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
    </asp:GridView>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>
</p>
```

Comment: You must edit your request to
DELETE  FROM [children] where [ChildID] =

Comment: Yep, your sql-syntax is broken. You dont delete columns from a table but full records. And if you leave the `WHERE` part it will delete all records everytime you delete one in your gridview.

Comment: Ok so both of these comments say different things, one says to leave 'where', the other says not to. I've tried both ways, and changing to "DELETE FROM [children] where [ChildID] =" gives me a syntax error "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the delete functionality without coding and only by using the designer. So add an `SqlDataSource` for your `GridView` and in its configuration window click on Advance and then check the checkbox of **Generate INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements**. That is all. Later, you can modify the code generated.

Comment: And this will make it so that the delete buttons next to the table entries work?

Comment: @ACostea yes, try it.

Comment: Oh my god.. So it was really that easy? Why is there so much emphasis on manually entering code when it is as simple as adding a data source? Am I missing something?

Comment: I mean, it does everything my specification asks. The delete links delete that user completely from the database table and it even refreshes the gridview on the webpage to show that the user is gone!

Comment: @ACostea, there are many ways of doing the same thing. This is one.

Comment: Ok well thank you for your simplified help, I will make you the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your cs code and image are different from each other. if you use delete command you should change to 'delete from xxx where yyy' format. but your select command seems ok.

Comment: Really? The only difference is I didn't include the commented out code from the screenshot in the pasted code. Either way, I changed the delete command to ("DELETE FROM [children] where [childID]=", connect) and I get a new syntax error: "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Comment: " DELETE FROM [children] where [childID]='5' "

Comment: Why '5'? Sorry for asking but I just like to have an understanding of what i'm doing rather than just pasting code.

Comment: Also, by adding the '5', when I then click delete, the gridview disappears from the web page but the table is still in the database, including the entry that I clicked delete on

Comment: It is just for example. Which row do you want to delete you can write its id instead of 5. sorry for less explanation.

Comment: Hmm, I want to delete whichever row it is that i'm clicking the delete button on. I don't know if this makes sense but say I click the delete button next to 'Katie', I want katie to be deleted from the database table

Comment: if 'katie' is firstname and 'children' is tablename (i thought it is name) (after atabrizi's answer) you can use this;  delete from children where firstname='katie'

Answer (score 0):

when you use delete you must not use columns name. it is wrong. the correct format is : delete from "tablename" where ....

Comment: Ok so a few people have said this, I have updated my code to show how it looks now but I still get an error: "Incorrect syntax near '='." when pressing the delete links.

Answer (score 0):

Clear Bookmarks before

```
 string ChildID=GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

and update  request

```
DELETE FROM [children] where [ChildID]='"+ChildID+"'
```